# Weak convergence in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

If $X$ is a Banach space, $X'$ its dual and $x,x_n\in X$ and $x',x_n'\in X'$, then the following implication holds:

> $x_n\to_w x$ (weak convergence) and $x_n'\to x'$ in $X'$ $\implies$ $x_n'(x_n)\to x'(x)$

I tried the following:

$$\left|x_n'(x_n)-x'(x)\right|\leq \left|x_n'(x)-x'(x)+x_n'(x_n-x) \right|\leq\|x_n'-x\|\|x\|+\left|x_n'(x_n-x)\right|$$

The first term tends to zero since $x_n'\to x'$. I'm not so sure about the second term. Does the weak convergence $x_n\to_w x$ imply that this term tends to zero as well?

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
|x_n'(x_n)-x'(x)|\le|x_n'(x_n)-x'(x_n)+x'(x_n-x)|\le\|x_n'-x'\|\cdot\|x_n\|+|x'(x_n-x)|
$$
and the sequence $\|x_n\|$ is bounded because it converges.

Comment: Typo fixed. ---

Comment: Another typo fixed...

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is quite simple, as Jonas showed. Here's a fun way to look at it.

Let $K=\{x_n'\}\cup\{x'\}$. Then $K$ is a compact metric space. Regard $x_n$ and $x$ as functions from $K$ to $\Bbb C$. Uniform Boundedness shows that $||x_n||$ is bounded, and this shows that our family of functions from $K$ to $\Bbb C$ is *equicontinuous*. And $x_n\to x$ pointwise on $K$; so Arzela-Ascoli shows that $x_n\to x$ *uniformly* on $K$.

(Don't think that's fun? Sorry, seems like fun to me...)

Comment: Not only is that fun, but also instructive. But a few things remain unclear to me. Is this what you had in mind? $x_n$ and $x$ can be considered as functions $K\to \Bbb C$ by $k\mapsto k(x_n)$ for $k\in K$ (same definition for $x$). We have $$\sup_n |x_n(k)|=\sup_n|k(x_n)|<\infty$$ by weak convergence. So, uniform boundedness yields $$\sup_n \|x_n\|<\infty$$ Now since $\{x_n,x\}\subset C(K)$ is compact, it is in particular equicontinuous by Arzela-Ascoli. Moreover, on $K$ we have pointwise convergence $x_n\to x$, hence also uniform convergence using equicontinuity.

Comment: That is, we have $$\sup_{k\in K} |x_n(k)-x(k)| = \sup_{k\in K} |k(x_n)-k(x)|\to 0$$ hence in particular $x_n'(x_n)\to x'(x)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ulrich: Is that OK? Looking back at it, I'm actually not sure where we used $x_n'\to x'$ in $X'$. Did we use that in saying that $K$ is compact in $X'$?

Comment: @TheRealBritneySpears Yes, the fact that $x_n'\to x'$ is exactly why $K$ is compact. Everything you write above seems correct on first glance, and yes, it's all just an elaboration of what I had in mind, with one exception: You derive the equicontinuity from A-A. That's perfectly correct, but if you're curious what I had in mind is that the equicontinuity is _immediate_ from the fact that $||x_n||$ is bounded: If $||x_n||\le N$ for all $N$ then you just take $\delta = \epsilon/N$ in the definition of "equicontinuous".

Comment: @TheRealBritneySpears I must say I had no idea the _real_ Britney Spears knew any math! We should get together sometime. For purely mathematical reasons, of course.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich, I was just trying to fill in the details in your argument as a means for revising stuff A-A/uniform boundedness. Killing this fly of an exercise with a bazooka was fun; perhaps the most fun thing I did since shaving my head.